# Google GeoChart Visualization API - city plotting in wrong location

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-visualization

For some reason on a site I'm working on, "San Francisco" is placing a marker in Louisiana in a Google GeoChart Visualization. I've even tried changing it to "San Francisco, CA", and even "San Francisco, CA, USA" and it's still plotting it in Louisiana.

You can see the incorrect marker here: http://galmeetsglam.com/travel/

Part of my code:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

data.addColumn('string', 'Slug');
data.addColumn('string', 'City');           
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p:{html:true}});

/* Locations */
data.addRows([
    ['london', 'London', 1, '<h1 class="tooltip-h1">London</h1>'],
    ['london', 'London', 1, '<h1 class="tooltip-h1">London</h1>'],
    ['new-york-city', 'New York City', 1, '<h1 class="tooltip-h1">New York City</h1>'],
    ['san-francisco-2', 'San Francisco', 1, '<h1 class="tooltip-h1">San Francisco</h1>'],
    ['san-francisco-2', 'San Francisco', 1, '<h1 class="tooltip-h1">San Francisco</h1>'],
]);
```

The odd part is other cities are plotting just fine (London and NYC). Not sure why SF is being screwy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are using `san-francisco-2`, but you should use either `San Francisco` just as your second column or  give the iso code : `US-CA` . So:

```
data.addRows([
    ['london', 'London', 1, '<h1 class="tooltip-h1">London</h1>'],
    ['london', 'London', 1, '<h1 class="tooltip-h1">London</h1>'],
    ['new-york-city', 'New York City', 1, '<h1 class="tooltip-h1">New York City</h1>'],
    ['San Francisco', 'San Francisco', 1, '<h1 class="tooltip-h1">San Francisco</h1>'],
    ['San Francisco', 'San Francisco', 1, '<h1 class="tooltip-h1">San Francisco</h1>'],
]);
```

Comment: Yea, I had the slug and the city name backwards. I just rearranged them and it's good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer in the Google Visualization API Forums.

Basically GeoChart uses the first element for geocoding. I had my category slug first (which I'm using for the filtering mechanism with Isotope).

So if I rearrange my data to be:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

data.addColumn('string', 'City');
data.addColumn('string', 'Slug');           
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p:{html:true}});

/* Locations */
data.addRows([
    ['London', 'london', 1, '<h1 class="tooltip-h1">London</h1>'],
    ['London', 'london', 1, '<h1 class="tooltip-h1">London</h1>'],
    ['New York City', 'new-york-city', 1, '<h1 class="tooltip-h1">New York City</h1>'],
    ['San Francisco', 'san-francisco-2', 1, '<h1 class="tooltip-h1">San Francisco</h1>'],
    ['San Francisco', 'san-francisco-2', 1, '<h1 class="tooltip-h1">San Francisco</h1>'],
]);
```

It works perfectly. Just answering this myself for any future visitors with the same question.